# Handiling Background image opacity for different display modes

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I'm using an image in the background of a page via body tag and for giving opacity to that image I'm using linear-gradient for background image as in the following code.

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.5), rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.5)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/159731/pencil-education-pencil-sharpener-art-159731.jpeg);
}
```

The problem with this code is the image is not visible in some display modes of TV like Gaming, Movie, User etc.. with different brightness levels.

Is there any other way to handle the background image opacity of image in body tag or any solution to handle the opacity with the same code for different display modes by getting the brightness levels of the monitor..

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxavcd05/)

Comment: what if you fake the background with a pseudo-element and handle the `opacity` values https://jsfiddle.net/sxavcd05/2/

Comment: In the fiddle you have provided the text on top also gets the opacity, if body:after is used then its woking fine. I'll check this method.

Comment: You just need to handle the index https://jsfiddle.net/sxavcd05/3/